# int x = time(NULL); => SEGFAULT?

Tags: c, time, segmentation-fault

Everything I see says this how I get a sensible parameter seed a random number with.

```
int seed = time(NULL);
```

segfaults. So does

```
time_t seed = time(NULL);
int seed = (int)time(NULL);
```

etc. etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The problem lies else where part of the code which you did not show, I believe.

Comment: Can it be that time (time_t *dest) have dest *mandatory* on your system? Try time (&seed) and see if it works, please

Comment: Run this through `gdb` and see *where* it segfaults.

Comment: The crash is some place else.

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable program that faults for you? The bug is most likely in code you are not showing.

Comment: @Senna, `time` does not require a non-null argument, at least according to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html), probably also according to ISO C. For the `&seed` version, that certainly should be the `time_t` one, not the `int`, to avoid memory corruption.

Comment: @MvG True, still worth checking. I like an idea with NULL being defined as something else, too.

Comment: As for seeding a random number generator, consider `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, as the kernel can provide much more entropy that way. Particularly important if your application involves security, or multiple processes might get started within the same second.

Comment: I expect you are right David. Thought there might be an obvious answer though.

Comment: Good thought MvG, I will almost certainly be starting lots of versions at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing that springs immediately to mind is that someone has redefined `NULL` to be non-zero. If you pass a non-null pointer, it will try to write to that memory, which may cause a segfault.

Quick check is to try `time(0)` instead.

Failing, that, it could be caused by corruption elsewhere, best bet in that case would be to single-step through it with a debugger.

Also make sure you've included the correct header. In systems where an integer (the default for parameters in compilers following earlier standards) is a different size to a pointer, you may be causing stack misalignment. I've seen this sort of effect on some 64-bit systems.

Comment: time(0) -> success. It seems that NULL somehow doesn't work. I'm almost certain I haven't redefined it myself. Is there anything you know of that does. I'm only using common headers: #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <time.h>

Comment: Nothing _should_ touch NULL, it would break a good deal of code. If your compiler supports preprocessor output like `gcc -E` (from memory), you can check that.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t seed = time(NULL);
    return 0;
}

// gcc x.c && ./a.out
// echo $?
// > 0
```